# Is there a way to fix home folder permissions remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ssh

I have a remote ubuntu computer that I connect to via SSH. The remote computer has only one user. I accidentally changed the user's home folder permissions (to 555, I believe) and because of that I can no longer ssh in. Is there a way to fix the permissions remotely?

Comment: Do you normally login using a password or a private key? Do you connect from another Ubuntu computer, or a Mac, or a Windows PC (in which case, do you use Cynwin ssh, or Putty, or something else to connect?)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you may be able to run commands over ssh even though you cannot start a login shell over ssh.

This may work

```
ssh remotecomputer chmod 775 .
```

Comment: I get the same permission denied error trying to run this.